# msbuild, исключение проекта из сборки

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Существует ли способ исключить проект из решения при сборке msbuild'ом ? Обычно, вызываю так:

```
start /WAIT /B msbuild servers.sln /p:configure=debug /m
```

Знаю, что существует параметр `/t`, с помощью которого можно перечислить проекты, которые должны учавствовать в сборке. Но вот как убрать проект - увы. Кто что подскажет ?

Comment: Вариант с перечислением/отдельной сборкой только нужных проектов по каким-то причинам не подходит?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, вообще - конечно подходит. Просто часто приходится собирать подобного рода проекты, хотелось бы делать это без лишних заморочек - а именно - исключая один проект из решения.

Comment: Если операция довольно частая - может быть имеет смысл промежуточный скрипт написать или custom task для msbuild, который будет понимать такой ключик, генерировать список проектов исключая нужный, и далее уже как обычно собирать.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну, если я Вас правильно понял - то это как-раз то, о чем я говорил выше - использовать ключ /t ?

Comment: Ага, скрипт получает список проектов из sln файла, убирает из него ненужные, и далее через /t запускает msbuild например.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, хорошая идея, мне нравится. Хотя бы потому, что это будет не просто перечесление проектов в ключе /t, а тут еще их нужно будет из решения вытащить )) Спасибо !